# Android Emulator: where to write command line "emulator.exe -avd -dns-server?"

Tags: command-line, android-emulator

I'm trying to connect my android emulator applications to the internet, and this blog (http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html) says I should write the command line i.e:

```
emulator.exe -avd MapsDevice2.2 -dns-server 192.168.1.1
```

But how?

Do I use the `cd C:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the directory where the `emulator.exe` file is located (you installed the tools in a directory you should be able to relocate, and then look for the correct subdir).
It should look something like

```
c:\ *something you did* \android-sdk-windows-1.5_r2\tools\
```

so it is in the tools dir of the SDK dir.

You can ofcourse run the command from any directory, but then you should prepend the path, so that boils down to the same.